# Integers $m$ so that $m+2011\mid m^3+2011$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$m+2011\mid m^3+2011$$

I don't know how to approach this. Tried seeing the ending digits of cubes, looked at divisibility cases of $2$ and $3$. The possible given answers are more or less all squares of $2$ or multiples of $32$, but I don't see what conclusion I can get from that.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Set $m+2011=y$  so $m$ will be integer $\iff y$ is

$$\dfrac{m^3+2011}{m+2011}=\dfrac{(y-2011)^3+2011}y=y^2-3\cdot y\cdot2011+3\cdot2011^2+\dfrac{2011-2011^3}y$$

So we need $y|(2011-2011^3)=-2011(2011^2-1)$

Comment: Can you spell it out to me? How do we know that your criteria is enough to limit $m$ to all the true values? Do I just check the amount of divisors $2011*2010*2012$ has to find the answer?

Comment: @JohnDoe, Please find the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $m+2011|m^3+2011^3$ as well.

Comment: How do I use that to my advantage?

Comment: You will reach the same conclusion as lab bhattacharjee reaches: $m+2011$ divides $2010 \times 2011 \times 2012$.