# Divisibility Problem in Number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Does somebody know how to solve divisibility problems like this, or this problem specifically? It‘s an Olympiad type problem, but I can‘t find a solution...
Do I need to solve it via modular arithmetic?
Any and all help will be greatly appreciated, thank you all in advance!

For which positive integers n is it true that
$$n+2019|n^2+2019$$

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h495766p2783637 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306583/integers-m-so-that-m2011-mid-m32011 for related problems.

Comment: Applyu the same method(s) as in the linked dups.